# How to monitor network requests made by a Python application

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

What would be a good way to monitor network requests made from a Python application , in the same way that the browser console does (usually in the "Network" tab)?

Ideally, this would display informations such as:

- url requested
- headers
- payload (if any)
- time the request was sent
- time the response was received
- response headers and payload
- timeline

This is mostly for debugging purposes, as the actual requests I want to track are made by third-party imports. A rich console similar to Chrome or Safari network tabs would be the absolute dream obviously, but there might be some "functional equivalents" in command-line mode as well.

Update: using macOS with root access

Comment: does `tcpflow` on the relevant `PID` not cut it? do you want something with a web interface? If so - rolling your own flask app by adding a custom closure to your `request` code that can spy on the relevant data and dump it into a table should not be too hard

Comment: You would need more details, e.g. such as the OS, network library used by those third-party libraries, as a generic approach may not be viable if there is a mixture of libraries used (especially if they use native library extensions).  If your dependencies are specific (e.g. `requests`) you can probably inject/override certain hooks to gather how they are being used.  If you are on Linux (or *nix), a much more generic solution is to [use `strace`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11709/how-can-i-capture-network-traffic-of-a-single-process), and then parse the logged output.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it, or looking for tool recommendations? Because the former is too broad, and the latter is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Without details of the operating system you are using it on, and whether you have root access, it is difficult to give a definitive answer.

However, you should consider using Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org), which gives you pretty good insights into exactly what traffic is going from your application to the Internet and vice versa.